# All form disappear until IIS reset

Tags: wffm

Sitecore 8.2 rev. 170614 WFFM 170518 SXA 1.2 rev 161216.

Currently I have a problem with my production environment.

All forms using WFFM disappear and I need to restart IIS to make it appear again. Note there are no cache configured on the forms.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: 1- When does this happen?
2- Can you try on CM box where the context DB is master?

Comment: It's happen one or two times each month. Currently our solution is to restart prod server one time each month but it's anoying. I can't reproduce this on CM rarely on staging envirnoment.

Comment: Anything in sitecore logs on the CD box when this happens? It is almost like the WFFM forms items are cached and disappear once the cache expires.